# How to check if all List are identical in efficient way

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

for each user we have 0 or N lists of cities, list contains unique values only.

what is the efficient way to check if user lists are identical (order  doesn't matter, all values are case insensitive) ?

this is user model:

```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @ToString
  static class User{

     private Map<Integer, List<String>> cities;

  }
```

this method should compare all user List:

```
  private static boolean isListsIdentical(User user) {
      user.getCities().values().forEach(cities -> {
         // if all list are identical return true
         });
      return false;
  }
```

here is the main method for test:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     User user = new User();
     Map<Integer, List<String>> cities = new HashMap<>();
     cities.put(1, Arrays.asList("New York City", "London", "Paris", "Tokyo", "LA" ));
     cities.put(2, Arrays.asList("Beijing", "Hong Kong", "Chicago"));
     cities.put(3, Arrays.asList("New York City", "London", "Paris", "Tokyo", "LA" ));
     cities.put(4, null);
     user.setCities(cities); //user may have 0 or N lists

     System.out.println(isListsIdentical(user)); //should return false in this case

  }
```

Comment: Does order matter, i.e. is [New York, London] identical to [London, New York]?

Comment: Order doesn't matter, both are identical

Comment: I think if order doesn't matter, the inputs to compare should be `Collection` to reflect this.

Comment: *Order doesn't matter, both are identical*  Well that was important information.  You should include two equal but out of order lists in your example.  Do your lists contain duplicate cities?  Are they case insensitive?  Please include all pertinent information.

Comment: order  doesn't matter, all values are case insensitive, and list contains unique values

Comment: It is worth noting that it is mathematically impossible to get a "yes they are equal" in better than `O(NK)` where `N` is the number of lists and `K` is the max list length.  But you can get a "no, some are not equal" in `O(1)` in the best case.  There are lots of "short circuits" in cases where the answer will be "no".

Comment: @ZakFST oh, "all values are case insensitive" is crucial and changes everything. That information should have been included from the beginning

Comment: @ZakFST what happens if one user has `{1=null, 2=[]}`? Is null and empty considered equal or not equal? (since your example specifically mentions a null value)

Comment: @knittl, they are equal, as in both cases user does not have values in his list of cities

Comment: @ZakFST the solution to your problem becomes more and more complicated with every detail that you disclose. Would be good if all those requirements were already included in the initial question, without having to ask for every single one of them :)

Answer (score 1):

`Map.values()` returns a collection so you need to use an `Iterator<List<String>>` to loop over the lists.  Since you want to see if the lists are all equal, you just need to compare the first to each of the rest.  **For two lists to be considered equal, equal values must occur in the same position and have the same size.  Otherwise, use a `Set` (i.e `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`**.  First, test to ensure the lists are the same size, then check to see if the contents are the same and in the **same order**.

```
private static boolean isListsIdentical(User user) {
    Collection<List<String>> values = user.cities.values();
    if (values.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    Iterator<List<String>> iter = values.iterator();
    List<String> baseList = iter.next();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        // return false on first mismatch.
        List<String> test = iter.next();
        if (test.size() != baseList.size() || !test.equals(baseList)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Updated due to change in requirements.  Similar to the above answer but assumes a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>` is used.  This does not ignore case.  To make it efficient I recommend you ensure that the cities all have the same case, upper or lower.  That way you won't have to be as careful upon entry.

```
    Collection<Set<String>> values = user.cities.values();
    if (values.size() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    Iterator<Set<String>> iter = values.iterator();
    Set<String> baseList = iter.next();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        // return false on first mismatch.
        Set<String> test = iter.next();
        if (test.size() != baseList.size() || !test.equals(baseList)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the comments clarified that order inside the lists/collections does *not* matter, the easiest is probably to copy to a Set and simply check the sets for equality.

```
private static boolean isListsIdentical(User user) {
  final Collection<List<String>> allCities = user.getCities().values();

  if (allCities.isEmpty()) return true;

  final Set<String> cities = nullOrSet(allCities.iterator().next());
  for (final List<String> cityList : allCities) {
    if (!Objects.equals(cities, nullOrSet(cityList))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

private static <T> Set<T> nullOrSet(final Collection<T> collection) {
  return collection != null ? new HashSet<>(collection) : null;
}
```

Because your map contained null values, the code has to become a bit more complicated. Avoid nulls if possible!

A simple optimization could be checking sizes before copying to sets (but probably not worth the effort for small collections).

NB. This will not work if one of the lists has a duplicated city entry, e.g. [[London, New York], [London, London, New York]] will still return true.

Regarding efficiency:

- Copying a list/collection to a set is O(n) (n being the size of the list
- Comparing a set with another set is O(m) (m being the size of the larger of the two sets)
- You have k lists in your map, giving you a total runtime complexity of approximately O(k*m), or naively O(n) (n here being the total number of cities). In other words: this scales linearly with your input size.

---

Since this answer was written, the "requirements" (or constraints) of the question have changed significantly and added a few critical points, one being the requirement of "case insensitive" comparison of city names. While the above algorithm might be easy to adapt by building new collections with all their elements mapped to `.toLowerCase()`, it would be very memory-inefficient, needing to copy all elements of all collections. While using higher memory, the overall complexity would still be O(n), but with a higher constant factor (and longer strings will require more memory and take longer to copy + lower case)

There is a method which can do with less memory overhead by using a `TreeSet` with proper `Comparator`, but the runtime complexity is O(k * log(m)). The TreeSet has the benefit of keeping the code quite clean and straight forward (abstracting away all that nasty lower-casing logic). The code considers `null` and `emptyList()` to be identical during comparison. If you can guarantee your map to never contain null, the code could be reduced even further.

I have written a JUnit 5 test to capture your requirements.

```
private static boolean isListsIdentical(final Collection<? extends Collection<String>> allCities) {
    if (allCities.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }

    final Collection<String> firstValue = allCities.iterator().next();

    // Compare size of collections (assumes O(1) "size()" calls)
    final int size = sizeOf(firstValue);
    if (allCities.stream().anyMatch(cities -> sizeOf(cities) != size)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Now compare contents of collections:
    // Using a TreeSet with CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER allows to compare city names while ignoring their case
    // TreeSet has O(log n) "add(item)" complexity
    final Set<String> collector = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    // We will compare everything against the first value from the map:
    if (firstValue != null) {
        collector.addAll(firstValue);
    }

    for (final Collection<String> cityList : allCities) {
        if (cityList != null && collector.addAll(cityList)) {
            // The collector set has changed => non-identical cities detected
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static int sizeOf(final Collection<?> collection) {
    return collection != null ? collection.size() : 0;
}

@Test
void test() {
    assertCities(true); // empty cities are always equal

    assertCities(
            false,
            Arrays.asList("New York City", "London", "Paris", "Tokyo", "LA"),
            Arrays.asList("Beijing", "Hong Kong", "Chicago"),
            Arrays.asList("New York City", "London", "Paris", "Tokyo", "LA"),
            null);

    assertCities(
            true,
            Arrays.asList("London", "New York City"),
            Arrays.asList("London", "New York City"));

    assertCities(
            true,
            Arrays.asList("London", "New York City"),
            Arrays.asList("New York CITY", "LONDON"));

    assertCities(true, null, null, null);

    assertCities(
            true,
            null,
            Collections.emptyList());

    assertCities(
            true,
            Collections.emptySet(),
            Collections.emptyList(),
            null);

    assertCities(
            false,
            null,
            List.of("Java"),
            null);

    assertCities(
            false,
            List.of("Java"),
            null);

}

@SafeVarargs
private static void assertCities(final boolean expected, final Collection<String>... cities) {
    Assertions.assertEquals(expected, isListsIdentical(Arrays.asList(cities)));
}
```

I changed the method to work on a Collection of Collections directly, because having a user class is just an unnecessary level of indirection for this question. You are really comparing lists inside a list, not a user. That these lists are wrapped in a user is irrelevant here.

Comment: Assuming that the lists you are testing have an `O(1)` `List.size()` method, then you can potentially get a significant speedup by testing list sizes before looking at the elements.  You can also (more or less) deal with the case of lists with duplicates ... by comparing the length of the list(s) and the final length of the de-duping set.

Comment: @StephenC yes, see paragraph #3 :)

Comment: Well ... yea ... but IMO it probably is worth it, even for small collections, since you save the cost of setting up and populating the `HashSet`.  Though I guess it depends on the probability that lists will have different sizes.

Comment: Updated my answer to handle the case of mixed-case cities. This is a new requirement that was only added later to the question.

Comment: Updated once again to consider empty lists and null the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
private static boolean isListsIdentical(User user) {
     final List<List<String>> nonNullCities = user.getCities()
             .values()
             .stream()
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
     set.add(nonNullCities.get(0).hashCode());
     for (int i = 1; i < nonNullCities.size(); i++) {
         boolean isNewValue = set.add(nonNullCities.get(i).hashCode());
         if (isNewValue) {
             System.out.println("Non Identical values found");
             return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why calculate a potentially-colliding hash code instead of simply using a `Set<String>`?

Comment: Yeah, you are right :)